# Assuming sshd allows only public key authentication, how do I log the fingerprints?

Tags: logs, openssh, sshd

With OpenSSH, how can I log the fingerprints of the keys used for authentication?

I would like to log it in production, so it would be best if this wasn't just some debug setting or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by setting `LogLevel` to `VERBOSE`, you would see logs like the following,

```
 sshd[1199]: Connection from 192.168.56.1 port 45811
 sshd[1199]: Found matching RSA key: XXXX
 sshd[1199]: Postponed publickey for root from 192.168.56.1 port 45811 ssh2 [preauth]
 sshd[1199]: Found matching RSA key: XXXX
 sshd[1199]: Accepted publickey for root from 192.168.56.1 port 45811 ssh2
```